# What is app indexing how to integrate it in android app and test the indexing?

Tags: android

I want an example of google app indexing as I am implementing the sdk following the link [Google App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app) but didn't get the app in search?

Answer (score 0):

App Indexing puts your app in front of users who use Google Search.

It works by indexing the URL patterns you provide in your app manifest and using API calls from your app to make content within your app available to both existing and new users.

Specifically, when you support URLs for your app content, Android and iOS users can go directly to it from Search results on their device.

Finally, Google uses App Indexing API calls from your app as a ranking signal for your URLs.

Details you can find from here https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/